# Annotation with AOP - works at method level while only the class is annotated

Tags: java, annotations, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm trying to create a custom annotation for my project. Here it is -

**DataSourcePicker** (annotation):

```
   import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
   import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
   import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
   import java.lang.annotation.Target;

   @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
       public @interface DataSourcePicker {

   }
```

I've implemented the `DataSourcePicker` annotation using AOP like this -

**DataSourcePickerAspect**:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class DataSourcePickerAspect implements Ordered {

    private int order;

    @Value("10")
    public void setOrder(int order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    @Pointcut(value="execution(public * *(..))")
    public void anyPublicMethod() { }


    @Around("@annotation(dataSourcePicker)")
    public Object pickDataSource(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, 
    DataSourcePicker dataSourcePicker) throws Throwable {
        //some code...
    }
}
```

With having these above all set up when I try to annotate my service class like this -

**(Good Approach)**:

```
   @Service
   @DataSourcePiceker
   public SomeServiceClass{     
       pubic void method1(){}
       pubic int method2(List<Integer> list){}
       pubic String method3(String a, String b){}
   }
```

The above code (`SomeServiceClass`) compiles fine. But neither of the methods are affected by the aspect(`DataSourcePicker`) I've written. 
But when I annotate my methods with `DataSourcePicker` it works as expected - all methods are intercepted by the `DataSourcePickerAspect`'s 
 `@Around` advice -

**(Not So Good Approach**, I guess):

```
   @Service
   @DataSourcePiceker
   public SomeServiceClass{
       @DataSourcePiceker     
       pubic void method1(){}

       @DataSourcePiceker
       pubic int method2(List<Integer> list){}

       @DataSourcePiceker
       pubic String method3(String a, String b){}
   }
```

Can someone help me how to can I achieve the `Good Approach`? All I want to create an annotation and annotate a class with it while all methods of the class will be affected.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try enabling `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` in your config and let me know.

Comment: Seems like the point cut is on methods, I think you need to define another pointcut and for class @Within for annotation and combine them to work.

Comment: It should be done by enabling AspectJAuto proxy. Worked??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `@annotation(my.fancy.Annotation)` you intercept annotated methods, while `@within(my.fancy.Annotation)` matches annotated classes, as documented in the [Spring manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators). Maybe you want to read it before using Spring AOP via trial & error.